# CORS errors because of internal app error

Tags: cakephp, cors, cakephp-4.x

I am creating a simple API with CakePHP 4, and I am having some issues with some `CORS` requests.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/myapp.api/elaborations/add.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Everything works with every other request and after some digging I've found that the error was an undefined index in my controller. If I fix that, the `CORS` error disappears. I just didn't see it in my log files, it's my bad.

It's a bit confusing seeing a `CORS` error because of a coding error though. I guess the issue could be in my `CORS` configuration, and hence this question.

This is what I've ended with, after a little bit of web search, trials and errors. I know it's ugly but I couldn't find anything better that actually worked.

How can I avoid having `CORS` errors for coding issues? I guess there is some redirect action somewhere, but I can't figure out how to avoid it.

```
<?php
namespace App\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;

class CorsMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    public function process(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        RequestHandlerInterface $handler
    ): ResponseInterface
    {
        // Calling $handler->handle() delegates control to the *next* middleware
        // In your application's queue.
        $response = $handler->handle($request);

        if ($request->getHeader('Origin')) {
            $allowedDomains = [
                'https://myapp.it',
                'https://www.myapp.it',
                'http://localhost:3000',
            ];
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

            if (in_array($origin, $allowedDomains)) {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
            }

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

            if (strtoupper($request->getMethod()) === 'OPTIONS') {
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: look here https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-cross-origin-request-headers-cors

Comment: That's the first thing I've tried of course, but this is what I get if I use that code (whth the proper `allow-origin` header): `Access to XMLHttpRequest... has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`. That's why I've ended up here https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/cakephp-4-cors-workaround-solved/8554 and created that middleware

Comment: As far as I've understood, one of the issues with the book's code is that it doesn't treat the `OPTIONS` method properly, thus failing the request. I've even tried to add the ugly `OPTIONS` condition to the book's code, but I'm still having errors: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do *not* access superglobals in CakePHP directly, always use the abstracted APIs! Also you shouldn't echo data manually, that includes headers, again, use the abstracted APIs! Using superglobals and echoing data will only get you in trouble, it messes up the testing environment, it can lead to data not being sent (properly), etc.

That being said, for proper CORS coverage you also need to modify error handling, as the error controller will create a new response instance. You should be able to process the request/response in a custom exception renderer, at `ExceptionRenderer::_getController()`, like so:

```php
// in src/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php
namespace App\Error;

use App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer;

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer
{
    protected function _getController(): Controller
    {
        $controller = parent::_getController();

        $cors = new CorsMiddleware();
        $response = $cors->setHeaders(
            $controller->getRequest(),
            $controller->getResponse()
        );

        return $controller->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

```php
// in config/app.php
'Error' => [
    'exceptionRenderer' => \App\Error\AppExceptionRenderer::class,
    // ...
],
```

Your CORS middleware would supply the `setHeaders()` method accordingly, where you set the CORS headers if required, based on your example it could look something like this:

```php
public function process(
    ServerRequestInterface $request,
    RequestHandlerInterface $handler
): ResponseInterface
{
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    $response = $this->setHeaders($request, $response);

    return $response;
}


public function setHeaders(
    ServerRequestInterface $request,
    ResponseInterface $response
): ResponseInterface
{
    if ($request->getHeader('Origin')) {
        $allowedDomains = [
            'https://myapp.it',
            'https://www.myapp.it',
            'http://localhost:3000',
        ];
        
        $origins = $request->getHeader('Origin');
        $lastOrigin = end($origins);
        if (in_array($lastOrigin, $allowedDomains, true)) {
            $response = $response
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $lastOrigin);
        }

        if (strtoupper($request->getMethod()) === 'OPTIONS') {
            $response = $response
                ->withHeader(
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                    'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
                )
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Error & Exception Handling > Custom ExceptionRenderer](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/errors.html#custom-exceptionrenderer)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware > Creating Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#creating-middleware)**

Comment: Thanks a lot ndm, your answer -almost- works out of the box. I'm still struggling with the headers though. If I use any `$resonse->withHeader` instruction the API breaks, and I have those CORS errors back. For instance, this works `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $lastOrigin);` but this doesn't: `$response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $lastOrigin);`. Everything else of your code is working great

Comment: @ToX82 You need to debug your app and the CakePHP internals further then to figure out where the headers are being lost. I've just tested the example as-is, and it works fine. Make sure that your code doesn't do any of these `exit()`/`die()`/`header()`/`echo` shenanigans anywhere else.